# single long line searching

Tags: awk, grep

I have a large document that is only 1 line, it spans multiple pages of `vi`.

Below is an extract of a small bit, I'm seeking to show text after `aria-label="`

I would then like to stop at `aria-selected=`

This would repeat many times along that single line and might contain more than one name.

I wondered about breaking the file up in to multiple lines with `aria-label=` as the line break marker and then grepping the lines.

There is always going to be a number after the `aria-label=` so that might help remove other matches?

```
style="background-color: #0B8043;"></div>Spike Bird</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div role="rowgroup"><div role="row"><div id="docs-revisions-sidebar-date-group-1551364837014" class="docs-revisions-sidebar-date-group" role="heading">February</div></div><div class="docs-revisions-collapsible-pane" role="presentation"><div class="docs-revisions-collapsible-pane-milestone-tile-container" role="presentation"><div class="docs-revisions-tile" role="row" aria-level="1" aria-expanded="false" id=":oj" aria-label="28 February, 14:40 Joe Bloggs" aria-selected="false"><div class="docs-revisions-tile-content-wrapper" role="presentation"><div class="docs-revisions-tile-header" role="gridcell"><div class="docs-revisions-icon docs-revisions-tile-arrow-button" data-tooltip="Expand detailed versions" aria-label="Expand detailed versions" data-tooltip-offset="-3" data-tooltip-unhoverable="true" role="button" aria-expanded="false" style="user-select: none;"><div class="docs-revisions-icon-img-mask"><div class="docs-revisions-icon-img docs-revisions-icon-arrow"></div></div></div><textarea class="docs-revisions-tile-text-box docs-revisions-tile-text-box-disabled" id=":og" spellcheck="false" rows="1" maxlength="80"
```

Comment: Is the document a well formed XML document?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
grep -Po '(?<=(aria-label=")).*(?=" aria-selected=)' file
```

it prints the value between `aria-label="` and `" aria-selected=`